# Python Pandas: search regular expression through dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to scan with Python a column of a pandas dataframe for each row if it does (1)  or does not (0) match to a regular expression and store the result a corresponding column of a dataframe.

Example:    search for '^a$'

b a b d a c f a e
must give
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

[visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02TY7.png)

My best guess for the moment is to make a list of the column, iterate through the list with a regular expression and try to convert the result via a boolean to 1 or 0...
But this is quite complex...

Comment: `df['col_name'].eq('a').astype(int)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pandas.Series.str.match` method to do just this which will return a `pandas.Series` of boolean values.

```
match_re = df["text_field"].str.match(r"^a$")
```

If you'd prefer to have integers in the end you can cast to `int` but I personally prefer using the `bool` dtype.

```
match_re = df["text_field"].str.match(r"^a$").astype(int)
```